# "Updates for SonarLint" dialog box is cut off

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, sonarqube, sonarlint

When i startup eclipse the SonarLint plugin checks to see if there are any updates available from the SonarQube server. If there are then the dialog box below is shown:
[image]

At the bottom of this dialog box are some links which I assume give me the option to download the updates but I can't see what they say in order to click on them. Has anyone experienced this before and knows how to fix the issue?

**Text from dialog box:**

> **Updates for SonarLint**
>
> Updates are available on SonarQube server xxx
>
> Do you want to download and update them now?

**My environment:**

- Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
- SonarLint 3.6
- Windows 10

Comment: File a bug report if one doesn't exist yet for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open ticket for that, and it should be fixed in the next release (4.0) of SonarLint for Eclipse: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-211

Comment: Looks like that's planned for release 08/Oct/18